# Test personal angular library, Error create component or module

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-components, angular-library

I try to generate a .spec.ts file that need to test a component, to do that  i need to create an internal component in the spec.ts script.

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { InputShowComponent } from './input-show.component';
import { InputsModule } from '../../inputs.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "lib-test-input",
  template: "<div></div>"
})
export class TestInputShowComponent {

}

describe("InputShowComponent", () => {
  let component: InputShowComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputShowComponent>;
  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ InputShowComponent ]
    });
    TestBed.overrideModule(InputsModule, {
      set: {
        declarations: [Test]
      }
    })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputShowComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    component.ellipsisClass = "";
  });

  it('should create the component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should apply ellipsis class when mode is "ellipsis"', () => {
    component.mode = 'ellipsis';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const scrollingTextContent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.ellipsis'));
    expect(scrollingTextContent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should apply table-td-data class when mode is "scrollable"', () => {
    component.mode = 'scrollable';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const scrollingTextContent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.table-td-data'));
    expect(scrollingTextContent).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should not apply any class by default', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const scrollingTextContent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.ellipsis'));
    expect(scrollingTextContent).toBeFalsy();

    const tableTdDataContent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.table-td-data'));
    expect(tableTdDataContent).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should apply animation when content overflows the container', () => {
    const offsetWidthSpy = spyOnProperty(component.scrollingTextContainer.nativeElement, 'offsetWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(100);
    const textContentWidthSpy = spyOnProperty(component.scrollingTextContent.nativeElement, 'offsetWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(120);

    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(offsetWidthSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(textContentWidthSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Add further expectations based on the animation behavior if needed
  });

  /* it('should set tooltip when the tooltip input is provided', () => {
    const tooltipText = 'This is a tooltip';
    component.tooltip = tooltipText;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const tooltipAttribute = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[pTooltip]')).nativeElement.getAttribute('pTooltip');
    expect(tooltipAttribute).toBe(tooltipText);
  });*/

  /*



  it('should not set tooltip when the tooltip input is not provided', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const tooltipAttribute = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[pTooltip]')).nativeElement.getAttribute('pTooltip');
    expect(tooltipAttribute).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should apply animation when content overflows the container', () => {
    const offsetWidthSpy = spyOnProperty(component.scrollingTextContainer.nativeElement, 'offsetWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(100);
    const textContentWidthSpy = spyOnProperty(component.scrollingTextContent.nativeElement, 'offsetWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(120);

    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(offsetWidthSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(textContentWidthSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Add further expectations based on the animation behavior if needed
  });

  it('should not apply animation when content does not overflow the container', () => {
    const offsetWidthSpy = spyOnProperty(component.scrollingTextContainer.nativeElement, 'offsetWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(120);
    const textContentWidthSpy = spyOnProperty(component.scrollingTextContent.nativeElement, 'offsetWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(100);

    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(offsetWidthSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(textContentWidthSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Add further expectations based on the animation behavior if needed
  });*/

});
```

but for the component

```
@Component({
  selector: "lib-test-input",
  template: "<div></div>"
})
export class TestInputShowComponent {}
```

VisualStudioCode Provie me an error:

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
> Argument of type 'ClassDecoratorContext' is not assignable to > >parameter of type 'string | symbol | undefined'.

I do some test and search and seems that happen cause the component it's not defined to a module, so

I try extenalize it and create aa new module, but  also for the module e get the same error:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestInputShowComponentComponent } from './test-input-show-component/test-input-show-component.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestInputShowComponentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class TestUtilComponentModule { }
```

> Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
> Argument of type 'ClassDecoratorContext' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol | undefined'

The error seems resolved only if i add the module to the main module, but i do not wanna import it cause is only for test porpouse. How can I avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same way as you have it but don't export it and maybe move it inside of the `describe`.

Like this:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { InputShowComponent } from './input-show.component';
import { InputsModule } from '../../inputs.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';



describe("InputShowComponent", () => {
  let component: InputShowComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InputShowComponent>;

  @Component({
    selector: "lib-test-input",
    template: "<div></div>"
  })
  class TestInputShowComponent {

  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
```

Make sure you get rid of the `export` keyword, that will cause issues. No need to `export` since it's not needed externally from this file.

Comment: I resolve it, but onestly i do not kown how :), 
I suppose the problem was related to an error in the main module where was duplicate imports but i tryt to replicate it withoout success. 
Remove the export from the class also  help resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem,
The error happen when i add in the tsconfig.json the include

```json
    /* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
    {
      "compileOnSave": false,
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "paths": {
          "incas-lib": [
            "dist/incas-lib"
          ]
        },
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "ES2022",
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "lib": [
          "ES2022",
          "dom"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "./projects/incas-lib/src/public-api.ts"
      ],
      "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
      }
    }
```

The error is in that row:

```json
"include": [
     "./projects/incas-lib/src/public-api.ts"
],
```

removing these row the error will be fixed.
Anyone can explain why?